# Scrapy push to Heroku get error: Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

Tags: python, heroku, scrapy

I have s scrapy project can crawl data and save to mongodb. I want to deploy it to Heroku.

I take a reference from Scrapy official website https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000216178-scrapy-cloud-vs-scrapyd-using-heroku-

I add requirements.txt:

```
pymongo==3.5.1
Scrapy==1.4.0
scrapyd==1.0.1
scrapy-heroku==0.7.1
```

scrapy.cfg:

```
[settings]
default = MyMovies.settings

[scrapyd]
application = scrapy_heroku.app.application

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
url = http://moviescrapy.herokuapp.com:80/
project = MyMovies
username = <My Heroku account>
password = <My Heroku password>
```

Procfile:

```
web: scrapyd
```

When type `git push heroku master` on terminal.

I get the error finally:

```
remote:            AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oj017as5/distribute/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to moviescrapy.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/moviescrapy.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/moviescrapy.git'
```

I think i have follow the official tutorial, why i still get the error ?

Should i add `distribute` somewhere ?

What step i miss it ?  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because scrapy-heroku  does not support python-3 instead use python-2 as a environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my python environment is 2.7.

Comment: I  too had a similar problem what i do, i add a runtime.txt and in it i mention ('python-2.7.15') and it worked for me

Comment: Do you mean add it in `requirements.txt` or another file `runtime.txt` ? Can you show the file content if you mean add it in `runtime.txt`. Thanks you.

Comment: Make another file name runtime.txt and let me know if you have any problem

Comment: I find the information https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes from your answer and it is working now. Thank you very much @Shumbham !